# Talend Open Studio and Eclipse - Link source from eclipse to talend open studio and export job as test

Tags: java, eclipse, talend

is it possible to use Talend Open Studio in conjunction with Eclipse. I want to link my eclipse developments (sources) directly as source code to talend and use my classes inside.

What I'm trying to do is, write for e.g. testjobs in Talend Open Studio for my Eclipse java developments without the need of compiling my eclipse developments as a jar. So they should share the same workspace also and Talend should be aware of my classes and have my classes in the class path of the jobs.

Will this be possible and if so, does anyone know a good example or how I have to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a beginner with Talend Open Studio (**TOS**) and I'm using **TOS** for Data Integration (**TOS-DI**).

**TOS-DI** is based upon Eclipse Framework but it is a standalone "product" (in Eclipse sense) so, it has its proper rules for third party code integration.

For example, you can use your Java code as a Talend "routine" or in one of Talend tJavaXX components. But this is copy/paste, not classpath integration.

Another way could be to integrate in YOUR Eclipse environment, the Talend code. This is open source and you can get the code there : http://www.talendforge.org/trac/tos/browser/trunk

But if you need the complete **TOS** execution environment, this will not easily be useful for you...

Last chance (but I've not tested) is to try to change the classpath of **TOS-DI**, using the "Debugger" perspective, in the package explorer, on the ".Java" project, by changing the Build path. You could then add your source code, as an Eclipse project or as a source directory.

Let's give it a chance and keep us informed of your success ?